# Are characters on non-English keyboards encoded differently and possibly not valid xml?

Tags: xml

I have a legacy application in which people from different countries fill out Q&A and send them to our servers.  Once it hits our servers, everything is converted to XML to be able to pass in between servers easily.  I have been getting reports from a few users in non-English speaking countries that they're uploads are not getting through to the servers, and looking through the log files it seems to be choking on the answers that were given.

I had them take screenshots of the answers they were trying to submit thinking that it was non-English characters that are invalid XML characters, but everything in the screenshots look like normal characters (alpha-numeric, : and . mostly).

Even stranger, I've taken the same answers they have and uploaded the form using my (English) keyboard and did not encounter any errors.

Is it possible that even though the visual representation looks like normal ASCII characters they are actually encoded differently and causing issues since they're typed on a non-English keyboard?

Comment: Have you looked at the submission in a hex editor rather than a text editor? Do they look different?

Answer (score 0):

XML generally is UTF-8 encoded, perhaps your code isn't taking this into account?  If the UTF is in tag names this is implementation specific.  If the UTF is a value between tags, which it sounds like you have, it should be fine.

If the keyboard is from a latin/germanic language the ABCs and accents will match between them as the ASCII you know.  If you have another language with similar ABC glyphs, such as Russian w/ Cyrillic, they are encoded differently as they may not represent the sounds latin/germanic users know.  Japanese and Chinese even have their own latin subset in the unicode tables which are not ASCII, sometimes this is easy to spot because its usually fixed-width or an unfamiliar/unclean font.  These will fail generic string comparisons.  I believe some script languages like PHP have a function to shift various unicode characters to their aSCII equivalents.